# sqlalchemyを使いqueryを実行しても反映されない

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemyを用いてクエリを実行、postgresSQLサーバーで2つのテーブルから片方のテーブルのアップデートをしています。
エラーは出ませんが、実行もされておらず、ご教示いただけますでしょうか？
同じengineでread_sqlは問題なく実行されます。

```
connection_config = {
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'Pass',
    'host': 'xxx.x.x.x',
    'port': 'xxxx',
    'database': 'database1'
}
engine = create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
                      .format(**connection_config))

session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
)

sql = """
    UPDATE "TableA"
    SET "ColumnA" = "Table2"."ColumnA" FROM "Table2"
    WHERE "Table2"."ColumnB" = "TableA"."ColumnB"
    """ 

session.execute(sql)
```

Comment: `autocommit=False`を`autocommit=True`に書き換え、または`session.execute()`の後に`session.commit()`を入れると解決しますか？

Comment: autocommit=Trueで解決しました。大変ありがとうございます！